# UITextView large text in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have an `UIAlertView` with `UITextView`.
on `ViewDidAppear` I do `[textView setText:]` with a large text, but the alert shows an empty textView, and only after I touch the textView to scroll, the text appears.

What should I do in order to make the text appear in the textView in the alert, without scrolling it to "refresh" it?

Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];



    av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Terms of Service" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Disagree" otherButtonTitles:@"Agree",nil];


    UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 142)];


    [myTextView setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [myTextView setEditable:NO];

    myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    myTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 13;
    myTextView.clipsToBounds = YES ;

    [myTextView setText:@"LONG LONG TEXT"];

    [av addSubview:myTextView];

    [myTextView release];

    [av setTag:1];


    [av show];
```

}

Comment: Edit your question with code ..

Comment: Please provide the code for creating alert + textView.

Comment: Does it immediately show (without scrolling) when the text is short, say just one character ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have initially set message as **@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"** for `UIAlertView`. Set your `UITextView` first and then set `UIAlertView`'s message as textView's text.

Comment: No, I use the message parameter with the "\n\n" in order to place the UITextView in the alertView. The text is in the textView...

Answer (score 0):

Add \n characters in place of message in alert view . Then create a UILabel add add to alert view. Like this

`UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n",  @"Title"] message:@"\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NEVER_DISPLAY_BUTTON_TEXT otherButtonTitles:nil];`

```
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Text"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Text"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Text"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Text"];
[alert show];
newTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,-55,252,230)];
newTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
newTitle.font = [UIFont  systemFontOfSize:15];
newTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
newTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
newTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
newTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.message];
[alert addSubview:newTitle];
```

You might need to adjust size of Uilable to match in your alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Terms of Service" 
                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n\n\n",myTextView.text] 
                    delegate:self 
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Disagree" 
                    otherButtonTitles:@"Agree",nil
                  ];
```